# Python simple socket chat User connection and output of message

Tags: python, sockets

I am creating a simple chat in python 3 using socket

here are the code

CLIENT

```
#!/bin/python

import socket
import threading
import time

tLock = threading.Lock()
poweroff = False

def receving(name, sock):
    while not poweroff:
        try:
            tLock.acquire()
            while True:
                data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                print (str(data))
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            tLock.release()

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 0

server = ('127.0.0.1', 5000)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.setblocking(0)
rT = threading.Thread(target=receving, args=("RecvThread", s))
rT.start()

alias = input("Username: ")
time.sleep(0.2)

message = input(alias + ">>> ")
while message != 'q':
    if message != "":
        s.sendto(str(alias + ": " + message).encode('utf-8'), server)
    tLock.acquire()
    message = input(alias + ">>> ")
    tLock.release()
    time.sleep(0.2)

poweroff = True
rT.join()
s.close()
```

SERVER

```
#!/bin/python

import socket
import time

hostname = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000

clients = []

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((hostname, port))
s.setblocking(0)

iQuit = False
print ("Server Started.")

while not iQuit:
    try:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        if addr not in clients:
            clients.append(addr)

        print (time.ctime(time.time()) + str(addr) + ": :" + str(data))
        for client in clients:
            s.sendto(data, client)
    except:
        pass
s.close()
```

How do i print a string to the server when a user connect?

I have tried to add this string after you have insert the name

```
s.sendto(str(alias + " Connected").encode('utf-8'), server)
```

but the output is orrible for me

Another Question:
Why i get something like this when seding a message?

```
Username: User_A
User_A>>> Hello
User_A>>> How Are you?
b'User:A: Hello'
User_A>>> 
b'User_A: How Are you?'
b'User_B: Hi'
```

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your second question: You are printing binary strings, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615414/how-to-convert-binary-string-to-normal-string-in-python3) for more information.

Use `str(data.decode('utf-8'))` instead of `str(data)` when printing the message on the server or the client.

Concerning the first question: This should work if you send the "Connected" string just after asking for the user name. 
The string is decoded the same way as a common message if you include the `decode('utf-8')` and looks normal to me.

Comment: ok on the server is normal but when a new user connect he gets something like this


    `Username: b'127.0.0.1 Connected'`.

The problem here are two, 1] i have to press enter to see if user_B send something to me. 2] when a new user connect he gets all the previous data. how can i filter the data to send it to the right user? i was thing about using addr[2] that is a unique number of the user

Answer (score 0):

> i have to press enter to see if user_B send something to me.

You enforced this behavior by locking out the receiving thread during the `input` of a message. You have to make up your mind whether you want this or want incoming data to be printed while typing.
You might want to cf. [Simultaneous input and output for network based messaging program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34992925/2413201).